# Pointer to char array only contains last few letters of content

Tags: c

I have a program that forks (it's working as a C socket server) and that all works fine. Before I fork, I assign shared memory for two of my structs, which also works fine when I do this later on:

```
abc->results = "Heyyy";
```

When I access `abc->results` in another child process, I get "Heyyy" returned. However, my C program builds up a message then needs to display that message:

```
//Results msg
char msg[46];
strcpy(msg, " {0,");
strcat(msg, cScore1);
if(score1 > 80) {
    strcat(msg, ",Pass},");
} else {
    strcat(msg, (",Fail},"));
}
strcat(msg, "{1,");
strcat(msg, cScore2);
if(score2 > 80) {
    strcat(msg, ",Pass},");
} else {
    strcat(msg, (",Fail},"));
}
strcat(msg, "{2,");
strcat(msg, cScore3);
if(score3 > 80) {
    strcat(msg, ",Pass}");
} else {
    strcat(msg, (",Fail}"));
}

abc->results = msg;
```

When changed to this, I get random symbols appearing (weird squares and X's). Occasionally I can see the last `}` before the weird symbols. My guess would be that it has something to do with the size of `abc->results`, but it's a pointer:

```
typedef struct myStruct {
char* results;
} structA;
```

I'm fairly new to C, so any help is greatly received.

Edit:

Forgot one more bit of crucial information. The correct message is displayed when I write to the socket in the same process:

```
abc->results = msg;

printf(msg);
printf("\n");

n = write(sock, abc->results, 47);
```

The printf and write display the correct results. It's when I use it again in the child process it breaks (in a different function, writing to a different client connection):

```
n = write(sock, abc->results, 47);
```

The write function params are exactly the same as above, so I'm very confused why it isn't working!

Edit again:

I've changed the msg to `char * msg = malloc(45);`. However, now when I use it in the child process I get nothing:

```
void myFunction(int sock) {
int n;

n = write(sock, abc->results, 47);
//This is not displayed either!
printf("\nResults:");
printf(abc->results);
printf("\n");

if (n < 0){
    perror("Error writing to the socket");
    exit(1);
} else {
    printf("Results sent\n");
}
}
```

Comment: `char msg[46];
strcat(msg, " {0,");` <- Umm, `msg` doesn't contain a string yet, so you can't pass it to `strcat` which concatenates onto a string.

Comment: Sorry, that was strcpy. Mistyped it when I copied the code over here.

Comment: the call to `fork()` copies the current process.  anything done to update data in the the parent process, after the call to `fork()` will not be reflected in the child process.  I.E. the setup of the `abc` struct contents must be performed before calling calling `fork()`.  The question hints that the posted code is executed after the call to fork() rather than before the call.

Comment: @user3629249; No, as I have already shared the memory for abc before forking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`abc->results = "Heyyy";` is assigning a string literal which lasts for the lifetime of the program.

`abc->results = msg;` is immediately invalidated once `msg` goes out of scope at the end of your function.

This is why the first case works but the second one doesn't. In the latter case the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

The fix is trivial: allocate memory for `msg` using `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be something fairly trivial. Is this the correct way to allocate memory? char * msg = malloc(45 * sizeof(char));

Comment: It will do, but sizeof(char) is 1 as guaranteed by the standard so you can omit it. Also don't forget to `free` the memory at some point.

Comment: The message is empty now when used in the child process

Comment: Actually it's not just empty, it doesn't display anything in the child process =/